# Go to top of page when making Panel Visible

Tags: asp.net, panel

I have a simple 2 panel form that I am setting up. I created this button on my aspx page:

```
<asp:Button runat='server' ID='NextButton' Text='Half Way There Proceed' OnClick='StepTwoPanel_Click' />
```

And then this is in my aspx.cs file:

```
protected void StepTwoPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 StepOnePanel.Visible = false;

 StepTwoPanel.Visible = true;
}
```

When I use this, it works perfectly to go from panel one to panel two. Only one little problem. Instead of taking the user to the top of the second panel, they are near the bottom of the panel, exactly where they were on the page when they clicked the button in the first panel.

My question is, when the button click makes the second panel visible, how can it also direct the page back to the top?

Comment: This is normally something I'd do with javascript/jQuery. I would also do the showing/hiding of the panels in jQuery as well, unless I'm doing more than just a simple show/hide.

Answer (score 1):

make MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = false; 
When the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback property is set to true, the user is instead returned to the last position on the page.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yogesh12/PostBack12292006050702AM/PostBack.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps scroll to your desired location using Javascript?

*Your Button:*

```
<asp:Button runat='server' OnClientClick="ScrollTheThing" ID='NextButton' Text='Half Way There Proceed' OnClick='StepTwoPanel_Click' />
```

*Its Javascript Handler:*

```
function ScrollTheThing()  {

    // Code to scroll where you need

}
```

For exactly how to perform the scroll, these might give some ideas:
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Feb/24/Retrieving-Browser-Scroll-Position-in-JavaScript